# Обнаружения движения в видео

Tags: видео

У меня есть 30 3-часовых видео, на которых одной фиксированной камерой сняты разные выступления на сцене. Я хочу выбрать наиболее динамичные моменты на 1-2 минуты с каждого видео. Попробовал детектор движения в iSpy с низкой чувствительностью - как раз ловит хорошие моменты со сменой декораций и массовым перемещением персонажей, но берёт ровно с момента старта движения, нет возможности захватить чуть раньше, плюс нужно ожидать пока всё видео дойдёт до конца. Может уже есть какие-то более подходящие инструменты?

Comment: Готовый инструмент принципиально?

Comment: Нет, конечно. Готовый запрос в гугле - это уже ого-го

Comment: @JK_Action или есть готовый?

Comment: Ну я бы смотрел в сторону Gstreamer плагины искал.

Answer (score 1):

```
vlc.exe --video-filter=motiondetect "файл" --verbose=2 --file-logging --logfile=log.txt
```

даёт количество найденных изменений в каждом кадре
дальше надо разбираться